Keycloak 24.0.2: Invalid parameter: redirect_uri
I'm trying to set the "Valid redirect URIs" to some arbitrary host like "http://localhost:8080/" or "http://www.goggle.com/.
But when I try to bring up the Keycloak-Login page for my realm (see screenshots) I get this "Invalid parameter: redirect_url" shown before I can even login.
I've added another screenshot which shows the request in Postman. But the redirect_uri is still "invalid".

I have no idea why this happens.
Behind "http://localhost:8080/* is just some endpoint which displays a static page. So no tokens etc. are checked.
Please see the attached screenshots for more information.
Thank you in advance.
Best Regards,
Frank




You do see the difference in your configured and actually used redirect_uris?
Configured: http://localhost:8080/*
Actually used: http://localhost:7979/admin/vaadin-demo/console/
Either configure the actually used one, or use the configured one.

I've seen that but I don't know why this is happening. I edited the original question and added the screenshot from the postman request. But the problem perists.

I've figured it out. When you do it directly from the browser some parameters were missing. So I used Postman to assemble the request and test it, then copied the correct URL with all the parameters into the browser, made a adjustment in the Keycloak-Admin and now it works.
I get redirected to the URL I've provided.
